# Cara Ngatasi Ini Gimanya Ya

Tags: android

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.perpustakaanuas, PID: 11869
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

{com.example.perpustakaanuas/com.example.perpustakaanuas.DashboardActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1948)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1622)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4555)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:728)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4513)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:709)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4874)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4842)
at com.example.perpustakaanuas.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:60)
at com.example.perpustakaanuas.MainActivity.$r8$lam

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please use English, and maybe your problem is because the Activity has not been declared in `Manifest`